# How to test function that uses rand()?

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have a function that utilises the `rand()` function and I would like to unit test it... But I'm struggling.

I am currently using Phockito to help with mocking and mock returns etc

```
public function myFunction()
{
    return hash(
      'sha256', 
      'this is some random string: ' . rand()
    );
}
```

Test file:

```
public testFunction()
{
    $myClass = new MyClass();
    $result = $myClass->myFunction();
    $expected = /* Some hashed string I expect */;

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
}
```

I have thought about trying to Phockito::mock the class I'm working with, but all of the other functions that are connected in this process will be required to be mocked also... And that will be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

Either use a library like [php-mock](https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock) to mock php functions or refactor your function to accept your random as an argument like:

```php
public function myFunction($rand = null) {
  $rand = $rand ?? rand();
  // ...
}
```